# How to select records from table using union such that result of first query concatenates each result with corresponding result of second query?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I have a table with person name, his father and mother id and his age, i want to write a query such that its return the name of parent with his/her youngest child name. The table looks like this.

[image]

For now i have written query that returns the desired result.

`select a.Name, min(b.Age) from People a, People b where a.PersonID = b.Father group by a.Name
union
select a.Name, min(b.Age) from People a, People b where a.PersonID = b.Mother group by a.Name;`

Its returning output like this.

[image]

I want it to show output in this order.

`|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name         |     min(b.Age)   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Adam         |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Eve          |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Child1        |         9        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Child2        |         9        |
|---------------------|------------------|`

I want the query to execute and return first row of father name and youngest child and then return first row of mother name and youngest child, then second row of father name and youngest child, then second row of mother name and youngest child and so on.

Thank you...

Comment: Add "order by min(b.Age) desc, a.Name;" at the end of your query

Comment: You said you want query will return first row of father name and youngest child and then return first row of mother name and youngest child, then second row of father name and youngest child, then second row of mother name and youngest child and so on.  but your sample output does not seems to me same as your expectation. am i right?

Comment: What about the rest of the hierarchy?

Comment: Do you need ordering on PersonID column or a combination of (name, age) ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin yes you are right, the second query i.e. the query selecting mother name is returning columns in reverse order compared to first query i.e. query returning father name which is not what expect and i don't know why!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a subquery and give `min(b.Age)` an alias name then use multiple `order by`

```
select * from 
(
    select a.Name, min(b.Age) age from People a INNER JOIN People b ON a.PersonID = b.Father group by a.Name
    union
    select a.Name, min(b.Age) from People a INNER JOIN People b ON a.PersonID = b.Mother group by a.Name;
)t
order by name,age desc
```

**Note**:

avoid use comma `,` to connect tables, use `JOIN` instead of comma, because `Join` can let us more aware of the association between the two tables

Comment: I think he needs ordering on PersonID column and not name or age.